# How to synchronize with wxListCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I have a wxListCtrl that i want to keep in synch with a data structure. The user will be able to add, delete and modify the data from other controls on the frame, I want the list to update whenever the structure does. What is the best paradigm to use here?

One Idea I was considering was to implement the wxListCtrls paint event method, but i'm concerned with efficiency and it would be a pain to keep track of the selected item.

Right now I have created a "updateTable" method, and I just call it whenever the data structure gets modified. I'm pretty sure I'm going to create an infinite loop if I don't re-design.

I suppose i could pass a function object..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with a virtual list control. The wxPython demo has an example. I haven't tried that before. Personally, I use ObjectListView, which is a wrapper on top of the ListCtrl. I find it much easier to use. You can see how I do it in this article: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution.  Sorry I'm a bit late.

```
class custom_virtual_list(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns = None, contents = None, autoscroll = False):
        columns = [] if columns == None else columns
        contents = [] if contents == None else contents
        super(custom_virtual_list, self).__init__(parent, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VIRTUAL)
        self.columns = columns
        self.contents = contents
        self.autoscroll = autoscroll

        self.update_columns()
        self._update_count()

    def get_selections(self):
        sels = []
        sel = self.GetFirstSelected()
        while sel != -1:
            sels.append(sel)
            sel = self.GetNextSelected(sel)

        return(sels)

    def update_contents(self, new_contents = None):
        if not new_contents == None:
            self.contents = new_contents

        self._update_count()

    def OnGetItemText(self, item, col):
        return(self.contents[item][col])

    def update_columns(self, columns = None):
        if not columns == None:
            self.columns = columns

        self.DeleteAllColumns()
        for i, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            self.InsertColumn(i, column)

        self._resize()

    def _update_count(self):
        self.SetItemCount(len(self.contents))
        self._resize()
        self.Refresh()

        if self.autoscroll:
            self.EnsureVisible(self.GetItemCount() - 1)

    def _resize(self):
        for i, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            self.SetColumnWidth(i, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)
```

The user can update the contents by passing a new collection into `update_contents()`, or you could change `contents` into a property to do it more behind-the-scenes.

You can have wider contents than you have columns, (so a 2d list of `[[name, email_address, id], ...]`, and only the columns `["Name", "email address"]`), and it still works fine, too, which is nice, 'cause you can do things like keep relevant data together, yet hidden from the end user.